Does AddSingleton<LoginState>() method creates multiple instances if I host this web application in multi pod environment?
Do we have more than one LoginState objects if my applications is scaled to multi pod environment. I am trying capture logged in user email ids to a class object and I am registering it as Singleton using dependency injection. Does it this creates problem if the app is scaled out to multiple pods. I am invoking AddId(string emailId) method upon user login and making sure that logged in user emial id is unique. Calling RemoveId(string emailId) upon user logout. If there are multiple pods does this creates problem. If one of the pod goes down for some reason. User is forced to login Isn't it ?
public class LoginState
{
    private List<string> loggedInUsers
          = new List<string>();

    public void AddId(string emailId)
    {
        if (!loggedInUsers.Contains(emailId))
        {
            loggedInUsers.Add(emailId);
        }
    }

    public void RemoveId(string emailId)
    {
        if (loggedInUsers.Contains(emailId))
        {
            loggedInUsers.Remove(emailId);
        }
    }

    public bool IsUserLoggedIn(string emailId)
    {
        return loggedInUsers.Contains(emailId);
    }
}

//Register service
services.AddSingleton<LoginState>()


Each instance of the app would have it's own object
